# Exclude labels that are outside a designated region in Mapbox Studio

Tags: data-visualization, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm currently working on a visualization on Mapbox that's focused on a given region, let's say Texas for the sake of this example. I want to make it so this region is emphasized on the map, with everything else faded to the background.

So far I've managed to import Natural Earth's shapefiles into Mapbox Studio in order to make everywhere outside of Texas a shade darker:

[image: map of the southern united states with texas outlined in a lighter shade of gray]

This is great, but ideally I'd like to hide all of Mapbox's labels that are outside of Texas. I've been trying to use filters in Mapbox studio to "filter out" all of the items on each layer, but it appears their layer settings don't allow me to filter based on a geospacial attribute (only data attributes).

Does anyone know of a way for me to hide all city labels outside of Texas; either programatically on the js Mapbox GL library, or ideally via Mapbox Studio?

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your question... It's perfectly valid. I don't know how to do this but I am working on a project specific to Texas and I also had this same idea. I am very interested in following this. One idea (if you only need a few cities listed) is to disable the entire layer itself, and then add in custom points and icons for cities within Texas. It would work, but of course it doesn't seem to be the best method. With the reputation you have here, perhaps you can consider a bounty if no one else is able to answer. Surely this can be done a better way.

Comment: That could be a solution but sounds pretty tediuous (and would have to be repeated with each new region, which we have quite a few of). I'm going to give this question a bit more time to see if anyone pops in with a solution, otherwise I'll consider a bounty. Let us know if you think of anything in the meantime!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I know in mapbox studio you can filter labels by country (in the select data view, under filter, select iso_3166_1 and set it to the country of interest); But there seems no way to filter by subregion (state/province). I think this has to be done in the SDK, but not sure what direction to go down.

Answer (score 4):

In Mapbox Studio, select the layer.  Then click 'select data' and then 'filter'.  There should be an option to filter the layer by the ISO/parent.  I've done the same with admin-1 labels to restrict to only US
[image]